# Limit on a function involving natural logarithmns

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Consider the following question:-
$$\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{\ln(x+4)-\ln(7)}{x-3}$$

I would classify this question as "not knowing where to begin" so I cannot provide my detailed attempt.

The only clue I was able to notice was that $x+4=x-3+7$ which maybe can be exploited in some way.

Also, note that the answer is not indeterminate because if we plug $x=3$ into the function, then it yields $0/0$, which means that algebraic manipulation can be used to transform the function into an expression in which two *equal* terms-one in numerator and other in denominator which both equal $0$ (when $x=3$ is plugged in) can be cancelled so we can remove the $0/0$.

Note: The solution I am seeking is one where L'Hôpital's rule is not used, because it has not been covered in the course I am doing till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is figuratively the definition of a derivative in disguise. With a moustache. First substitute h = x - 3

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\ln(7 + h)-\ln(7)}{h}$$

Where have I seen this before?

$$\frac{dy}{dx} \text{ at } x = 7 =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(7 + h)-f(7)}{h}$$

Therefore your limit must be the derivative of the natural log evaluated at 7.

Your teacher wants you to make the connection between the derivative and the limit.

Comment: It might be easier to define $f(x)=\ln(x+4);$ then the answer is $f'(3),$ no disguises.

Answer (score 5):

Simply apply L'Hopital's rule once to get the answer.

$$\lim_{x\to 3}\dfrac{\ln(x+4)-\ln 7}{x-3}=\lim_{x\to 3}\dfrac{\frac{1}{x+4}}{1}=\dfrac{1}{7}$$

---

**Aliter $1$**:

Set $h=x-3$. $$\lim_{x\to 3}\dfrac{\ln(x+4)-\ln7}{x-3}=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\ln(h+7)-\ln7}{h}=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dh}\left(\ln(h+7)\right)\Biggr|_{h\to 0}=\dfrac{1}{7}$$

---

**Aliter $2$**:

Set $h=x-3$. And replace $h\mapsto 7h$. Use standard limits.

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ln(\frac{h+7}{7})}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+h)}{7h}=\frac{1}{7}$$

Comment: No, L'hopital's rule is specifically asked to not be applied because it has not been covered in the course I am doing.

Comment: just what i was looking for...thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are working $$y=\frac{\log (x+4)-\log (7)}{x-3}$$ when $x\to 3$.

To make life simpler, let $x=3+t$ to make
$$y=\frac{\log \left(1+\frac{t}{7}\right)}{t}\sim \frac {\frac t7 }t={\frac 17 }$$

Answer (score 2):

For fun:

1) Let $x \rightarrow 3^+$.

$\log (\frac{x+4}{7})^{\small{\frac{1}{x-3}}}.$

Set $y= \frac{1}{x-3}.$

Then

$\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}\log (1+\frac{1}{7y})^y=\log (e^{1/7})=1/7.$

2) Can you do $x \rightarrow 3^-$?

Used:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (1+\frac{a}{x})^x=e^a$, $a$ real.